# Scraping the data from the links simultaneously along with the data from the main page in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

the problem im facing here is that im trying to scrape this website of quotes

the website: https://quotes.toscrape.com/
what I intend to do is scrape the author's name,quote, and tags, and further simultaneously I want it to follow the (about) tag (which is a hyperlink) in each section and scrape the author's description and also his date of birth and save them all into a CSV file.

I've seen some similar questions on how to do something similar. But couldn't understand it clearly.

would love it if someone explained how to approach this problem, explaining how to use the meta/cb_kwargs, etc.

Heres, my code.

```
class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        "https://quotes.toscrape.com/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css(".quote"):
            author_link = response.css(".quote span a::attr(href)")
            yield response.follow_all(author_link, callback=self.author_parse)
            yield {
                "author": quote.css(".author::text").get(),
                "text": quote.css(".text::text").get(),
                "tags": quote.css(".tags .tag::text").getall(),
            }

    def author_parse(self, response):
        yield {
            "dob": response.css(".author-born-date::text").get(),
            "bio": response.css(".author-description::text").get(),
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `cb_kwargs` is the preferred method right now:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css(".quote"):
        author_link = response.css(".quote span a::attr(href)")
        author = {
            "author": quote.css(".author::text").get(),
            "text": quote.css(".text::text").get(),
            "tags": quote.css(".tags .tag::text").getall(),
        }
        yield response.follow_all(author_link, callback=self.author_parse, cb_kwargs={'author': author})


def author_parse(self, response, author):
    author["dob"] = response.css(".author-born-date::text").get()
    author["bio"] = response.css(".author-description::text").get()
    yield author
```